# mariadb:Couldn't execute 'SHOW PACKAGE STATUS WHERE Db='db_name'

Tags: mysql, mariadb

While taking dump of tables and stored procedure on mariadb 10.2.12, I am getting error `mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW PACKAGE STATUS WHERE Db = 'db_name'': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'PACKAGE STATUS WHERE Db = 'db_name'`

command I am using 
mysqldump -h hostname -u user -p --routines --triggers --all-databases > MySQLStoredProc.sql

Comment: Since `SHOW PACKAGE STATUS` was not introduced until 10.3.5, I wonder if the version of `mysqldump` comes from that version?

Comment: In this thread https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/2928 running `mysql_upgrade` fixed the issue. Didn't work for me though.

Comment: Apparently, this is caused by a new version of mysqldump running against an older version of the backend. A bug report has been filed: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-17429.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed.

On CentOS: "MariaDB-client-10.3.12-1" does not interwork with "MySQL server 5.6.26".

No fear:

What do we have?

```
rpm --query --all | grep -i maria
```

Let's go with an older version, 10.2.21, which is "stable".

Available at:

http://mirror.mva-n.net/mariadb//mariadb-10.2.21/yum/rhel7-amd64/

Get the old packages:

```
wget http://mirror.mva-n.net/mariadb//mariadb-10.2.21/yum/rhel7-amd64/rpms/MariaDB-10.2.19-centos73-x86_64-client.rpm
wget http://mirror.mva-n.net/mariadb//mariadb-10.2.21/yum/rhel7-amd64/rpms/MariaDB-10.2.19-centos73-x86_64-compat.rpm
wget http://mirror.mva-n.net/mariadb//mariadb-10.2.21/yum/rhel7-amd64/rpms/MariaDB-10.2.19-centos73-x86_64-common.rpm
```

Check the hashsums against the file available at

http://mirror.mva-n.net/mariadb//mariadb-10.2.21/yum/rhel7-amd64/sha256sums.txt

(that's not really good enough, the sums should NOT be on the mirror ... )

Downgrade existing:

```
rpm -Uvh --oldpackage MariaDB*
```

And it works for now.

Comment: Could you cite where you saw: On CentOS: "MariaDB-client-10.3.12-1" does not interwork with "MySQL server 5.6.26". 

I'd like to know where to watch for breaking changes like this

Comment: @mrichter Sorry for the confusion. It is not a citation but an empirical finding. I should have written "I can confirm that ...". I don't think anyone is tracking possible protocol compatibility problems between MariaDB and MySQL instances in particular ... you hit them when you hit them.